# Forced download

Tags: downloading, notification-bar, notification-icons, application-autoupdate

I had this icon in notification bar once I connected to wifi .. Google play auto update is disabled and application update comes with no red dot ... When I scrolled down the status bar, no notification about what is being downloaded ... In google play, no recent updated apps ... Any idea what was it or how to know what was being downloaded?
Kind regards,
Ahmed[image]